# useParams() from "next/navigation" is returning null when i am trying to test component with storybook

Tags: typescript, next.js, storybook

useParams() from "next/navigation" is returning null  when i am trying to test component with storybook. Please help on this if anyone can.

my method is here to read values.

```
"use client";

import { useParams } from "next/navigation";

export const useGmpParams = (): {
    locale: string;
    currency: string;
    ccode: string;
    slug: string;
    category_slug: string;
} => {
    debugger
    const { locale, currency, ccode, slug, category_slug } = useParams();

    return {
        locale: locale as string,
        currency: currency as string,
        ccode: ccode as string,
        slug: slug as string,
        category_slug: category_slug as string,
    };
};
```

useGmpParams() i am invoking from my isolated component called breadcrumbs.

```
const Breadcrumbs: FC<BreadcrumbsPropsTypes> = ({ breadcrumb }) => {

  const { locale, ccode } = useGmpParams();
```

sotrybook main.ts is here

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/nextjs';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  // Required
  framework: '@storybook/nextjs',
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials'],
};

export default config;
```

preview.ts

```
import { Preview } from '@storybook/react';

import '../dist/tailwind.css';

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {},
};

export default preview;
```

I am trying to get const { locale, currency, ccode, slug, category_slug } = useParams();

but getting null from  useParams().